# Proxy to get a url feed with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, proxy

I am trying to include a news feed area in an Ionic app I am developing, consulting feeds from other websites. But for some feed urls, the app complains about the absence of Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter. So I created a lambda function, which get the content from the url feed parameter and returns it to the client, adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header. You can see the code below:

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var url = event.queryStringParameters.url;
    https.get(url, (res) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res.headers);

      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
        rawData += chunk; 
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
         const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'text/xml, application/xml',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
            },
            body: rawData,
          };

          // callback is sending HTML back
          callback(null, response);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e.message);
          callback(e);
        }
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      callback(e);
    });
};
```

This works for most urls, but for one specifically (https://www.passblue.com/feed/) I get blocked by their firewall. It sends me back the following message:

*Access Denied - Sucuri Website Firewall - If you are the site owner (or you manage this site), please whitelist your IP or if you think this block is an error please open a support ticket and make sure to include the block details (displayed in the box below), so we can assist you in troubleshooting the issue.*

I tested it also from my local browser and it works correctly. I also created a local script in my computer to mimic the aws lambda function and it also gets blocked by the firewall. I am guessing that there are some header information I should be sending in the request.

Did anybody see this behaviour before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by replacing https node module with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) npm package. I am guessing that a newer approach is setting better headers in the request (resembling less of a DDOS attack).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var url = event.queryStringParameters.url;

    fetch(url).then((res) => {
      return res.text();
    }).then((body) => {
        const response = {
           statusCode: 200,
           headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'text/xml, application/xml',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
           },
           body,
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }).catch('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      callback(e);
    });
};
```